# Unexpected input 62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c appears in shell after writing buffers to stdout

Tags: c, linux, shell, buffer, stdout

The goal is to read a file and write the buffer directly to stdout so it can be used for further processing. This goes as expected for text files, images and pdf. But when reading a pdf file a weird input is displayed in the shell input namely: 62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c. I compiled test.c on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (14.04) trusty.

**Shell**

```
user@user-virtualmachine:~$./test
<prints binary data here
...
...
end of binary data>
user@user-virtualmachine:~$62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c62;9;c
```

when I check the md5sum it is a match so nothing strange there:

```
md5sum paper.pdf
5152a6c5b7deb364385fb3dd27c586db     paper.pdf

./test | md5sum
5152a6c5b7deb364385fb3dd27c586db     -
```

I have tried to look it up online and it said that some binary data might cause the shell to behave in an unexpected way when writing it to stdout. Can this problem be solved? The code is provided below.

**Test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    ssize_t bytes_read;
    char buffer[1024];
    int fd;

    fd = open("paper.pdf", O_RDONLY);
    if(fd < 0) {
     perror("Error in reading file");
     exit(1);
    }

    do {
     bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, 1024);
     if(bytes_read > 0) {
         write(fileno(stdout), buffer, bytes_read);
     }
    } while(bytes_read > 0);

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

PDF files are **binary** files.  While they can contain text, they can and do contain non-textual data.

To solve this problem:  don't dump binary data to your shell's output.  It doesn't matter where the binary data comes from - try `cat /usr/bin/bash`.  You'll get the same result.  The only way to prevent this from "messing up" your shell's output is to not do it.

Comment: The stdout will be piped anyway so it does not really matter for the way the program is intended to work, but it does leave a "mess" after execution which doesn't seem to be right. I guess I can safely ignore this strange occurrence but I still wonder whether it can be prevented. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @Gijs It can be prevented by not outputting binary data (specifically, control characters, especially `^[` (ESC)) to the terminal.

Comment: @FUZxxl So I guess it can't be prevented then since removing control characters from the binary would corrupt the file.

Comment: @Gijs Yes. Why do you output binary data to the terminal anyway?

Comment: If you want to view the contents of a binary file you should use a file tabulator, or make your own. This is tagged Linux but my favourite Windows file browser `xplorer²` from http://zabkat.com/ allows this, either in another window, or another pane in the main browser window.

Comment: @FUZxxl I made an RPC client that allows me to store data files on an RPC server (such as pdf's). The data files can also be retrieved and to verify that the transfer went as planned I use md5sum to check the file integrity. Like in the code presented above, the binary retrieved from the server can be checked this way. I just noticed that when only printing the binary you get this strange input hence the question.

Comment: @Gijs I see. A typical strategy to avoid this problem is to use the `isatty()` function to make sure that `stdout` is no going to the terminal, but this might not work in your particular scenario.

Comment: @Gijs - instead of piping via `./test | md5sum`, just use `md5sum < paper.pdf`.  Also, your code duplicates the functionality of the `cat` utility.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat